# can we integrate adobe acrobat pdf editor

Tags: apache-flex, pdf, flex4.5, acrobat

can we integrate adobe acrobat pdf editor to Flex application? Or is there a option to load and edit existing pdftext, pdfimage  using adobe flex?
I have used alivePDF library to create new Pdf documents. now I have to load existing pdf is there any pluggin or libraries?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  component like following

```
<mx:HTML id="htmlDocument" top="2" bottom="30" left="2" right="2" borderStyle="solid"
             location="{PATH.concat('#toolbar=1&amp;navpanes=0')}"/>
```

while PATH is the string in which PDF path is stored, and

> ## toolbar=1&navpanes=0
>
> is used to show Acrobat PDF Toolbar.
>   Let me know if you have any more query.